# Is there any way to bypass Google bot identification with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

I'm running Selenium on Python to retrieve data from google default web search, but after some time running my scraper, I got a captcha screen to solve. Is there any solution to skip this google identification? Or a solid way to solve captcha by code?

I'm currently running Selenium with Google Chrome, randomly changing user agents, waiting 3 seconds between each query, with headless flag = False

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
user_agents = {
    1: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    2: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    3: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    4: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    5: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    6: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    7: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
}
user_agent = '--user-agent="' + user_agents[random.randint(1,7)] + '"'
options.add_argument(user_agent)
```

[google captcha screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZU5x.png)

Comment: I have the same problems with this in my other projects. Really would be helpful if any one could answer this

Comment: I've found a solution that works for google images, but for regular search, my code still crashing. [https://github.com/Appiiee/Image-scraping-using-python/blob/master/image%20scrapping.ipynb](https://github.com/Appiiee/Image-scraping-using-python/blob/master/image%20scrapping.ipynb)

Comment: Hi, what seems to be the issue.

Comment: Normally when dealing with captchas there's either a div class='g-recaptcha' with a data-sitekey if it's V2 or script source with recaptcha code for V3.